# How to extract a string from a cell from right to left using a specific character that occurs more than once?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Normally I would just use the `RIGHT` function in excel to split it by finding a specific character such as `/` and outputting the string that I want.

However, I am finding trouble extracting `THISSTRING.txt` from `d/aaa/THISSTRING.txt`. With only one instance of `/` I would just use a function such as `=RIGHT(B17,LEN(B17) - FIND("/",B17))`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Objective:** To return the rightmost sub-string from a target string after the last occurrence of a character which appears several times within the target string.

This formula:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

Provides the correct result under the following conditions:

1. The sub-string to retrieve does not have more than 99 characters.
2. The sub-string to retrieve does not contain more than one space character together.

Example: *To retrieve a sub-string which is `123` characters long and contains the following characters* `1  ABC  XXX   123  XYZ`.

*Point 1* is easily solved by working with the length of the string instead of a fixed number:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))), LEN(A1)))
```

However *point 2* can't be overcome with the referred formula.

**Proposed solution:** The following formula returns the correct result regardless of the conditions mentioned above:

```
=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND( CHAR(12),
SUBSTITUTE(A1, "/", CHAR(12), LEN(A1) - LEN( SUBSTITUTE(A1, "/", "" )))))
```

*Note: I used non-printable character 12 which is very unlikely to be found in excel, change as required.*

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to get the rightmost:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way.....

`=REPLACE(B17,1,LOOKUP(2^15,FIND("/",B17,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B17))))),"")`

`FIND` generates an array of values, indicating the first position of a "/" in `B17`, but with the start point incrementing by 1 each time, which means that the last numeric value in that array is the positon of the last "/".

`LOOKUP` extracts that value from the array and we can use it in `REPLACE` function to replace all characters before and at that position with nothing, just leaving you with all characters after the last "/"

You'll get an error if there is no "/" in B17